# How to implement the keep-alive function on next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, keep-alive

I want to wirte a muilt tabs with the pages cache,so that jump to anothe page,the last page's data
can retain.In vue ,there's keep-alive function，but react.So I found a third party library to resolve it  (https://github.com/AlexSapoznikov/react-next-keep-alive).But I can't quite understand its documents，so I don't konw how to use it when unlike the examples it provides,just as the nomal conponent.

```
export default withKeepAlive(Buffertab,'Buffertab') ;


const withKeepAlive = (
  Component: (props?: Object) => JSX.Element,
  name: KeepAliveName,
  opts: KeepAliveOptsProps = defaultOpts
) => {
  const KeepAlive = (props: KeepAliveProps) => (
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-fragments
    <Fragment>
      <Component {...props} />
    </Fragment>
  );

<Buffertab />
```

But,it tell me Missing attribute 'children' in type '{}', but required in type 'keepaliveprops'.

Or, there are better ways to solve this problem can also be provided to me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your code block is trying to achieve, but `withKeepAlive` is imported directly from the library, e.g. `import { withKeepAlive } from 'react-next-keep-alive';`. The usage documentation seems pretty clear to me: https://github.com/AlexSapoznikov/react-next-keep-alive#usage. You add the `KeepAliveProvider` in your custom `_app`, then use `withKeepAlive` on the pages you want to cache.